# Adding String to Value in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, string, forms, concatenation

I have an HTML form which collects values in a format needed for a certain task. After completing the task, I would like to perform an additional task using the same values from the form without having the user enter the information in a second time.

The problem that I am running into is that the second task requires two of the fields to be formatted differently when they are sent to their destination.

Here is the array on the second script that is being sent where the keys on the left are being assigned the values on the right by the values from the form.

```
    $contactFields = array(
    // field name in myServer => field name as specified in html form
    'aaaaaaaa' =>  'email',
    'bbbbbbbb' => 'stuff',
    'cccccccc' =>  'morestuff', 
    'dddddddd' =>  'blah', 
    'eeeeeeee' =>  'blahh', 
    'ffffffff' =>  'blahh',
    'gggggggg' =>  'tobacco', //tobacco use
    'hhhhhhhh' =>  'amount', //face amount
);
```

What I am trying to do is add the string ',000' to the value of 'amount' taken from the user input. Again, I cannot just change the value on the HTML form because I need the value formatted differently for the first script.

I have tried

```
'hhhhhhhh' => 'amount'.',000',
```

No bueno. I also tried a similar method before the array, but to no avail.

For the field receiving the value of 'tobacco', I am trying to convert it from a 0 or 1 value, to a yes or no value. I tried this

```
    if ($tobacco == 1) {
    $tobacco = "yes";
} else if ($tobacco == 0) {
    $tobacco = "no";
} else {
    $tobacco = "?";
};
```

But that just caused the script to return a null value.

$Tobacco was originally assigned above the contactFields array as such

```
//

Assigns variables to input fields
$aaaaaaaa  = $_POST['email'];
$bbbbbbbb  = $_POST['aaaaaaaa'];
$cccccccc  = $_POST['bbbbbbbb'];
$dddddddd  = $_POST['cccccccc'];
$eeeeeeee  = $_POST['dddddddd'];
$ffffffff  = $_POST['eeeeeeee'];
$gggggggg  = $_POST['tobacco'];
$hhhhhhhh  = $_POST['amount'];
```

Any suggestions? Thanks. PHP is not my strongpoint.

Comment: You've tried $contactFields['hhhhhhhh'] = 'amount' . ',000'; and value is unchanged? And how do you assign the $tobacco variable?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the issue, but if you want to append that string to your array item you can simply use: `$contactFields['hhhhhhhh'] = $contactFields['hhhhhhhh'].",000";`  Also for your tobacco issue: `$contactFields['gggggggg'] = ($contactFields['gggggggg'] == 'tobacco' ? 'yes' : 'no');`

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I edited question to reflect how $tobacco was assigned. Kid Binary - When I add do that, value comes back as null. Robert Wade - I will try your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the array item you can do it this way:

```
$contactFields['hhhhhhhh'] = $contactFields['hhhhhhhh'].",000";
echo $contactFields['hhhhhhhh'];
// outputs
// amount,000

$contactFields['gggggggg'] = ($contactFields['gggggggg'] == '1' ? 'yes' : 'no');
echo $contactFields['gggggggg'];
// outputs
// yes
```

or you can set variables if you don't want to alter your array:

```
$newAmmount = $contactFields['hhhhhhhh'].",000";
echo $newAmount;
// outputs
// amount,000

$newTobacco = ($contactFields['gggggggg'] == '1' ? 'yes' : 'no');
echo $newTobacco;
// outputs
// yes
```

But as was mentioned, if 'amount' is truly a number, use number functions and don't store it as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works great for the amount field. And yes, I agree amount should be a number, but my instructions are to return value with commas so I'm storing it as a string. For the tobacco field I am returned a value of 'no' regardless of the initial input.

Comment: The statement for tobacco says that if the value of the array item With key ggggggg is exactly tobacco then return yes if anything else then return no what are the  possible values for this field?

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry I am new to PHP. I understand what it is doing now. I just need to change tobacco to 1. The values I have are 1 for yes. 0 for no. I believe once I do that it should work.

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Comment: Ah ok. I was confused because your example array had the string tobacco in the value spot

Comment: I went ahead and updated the code above for historical purposes.  Being new to PHP you should read up on data types.  The 0/1 values you were receiving were typical boolean values (0=false, 1=true). The reason people are telling you not to store numbers as strings is because it's much easier to manipulate a number in it's simplest form so you should always store it that way, then format it for your views as needed.  Same with booleans.  Cheers and good luck!